Bulk creation of calendars using Google Sheets
I have been trying to bulk create some Google Calednars using Google Sheets, prior to the importing of calendar data into each calednar.
I used Google Gemini to help with this and the following script was suggested. It even told me where I was going wrong when I made some mistakes but now I've hit a problem, it has been be able to help with me. The script Google Gemini gave me was.
function createCalendars() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    var calendarName = data[i][COLUMN_NUMBER_WITH_CALENDAR_NAMES];
    CalendarApp.createCalendar(calendarName);
  }
}

I modified it, following advice to this.
function createCalendars() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(Calendars_bulk_creation);
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    var calendarName = data[i][1];
    CalendarApp.createCalendar(calendarName);
  }
}


When I run it though, I get the error:
Error   
ReferenceError: Calendars_bulk_creation is not defined
createCalendars @ Code.gs:2

What I tried was to run the above script and what I expected was some calendars to be created. Obvioulsy that didn't happen.
Following advice from erik258, I updated the function to include double qoutes but that led to a different error.
function createCalendars() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Calendars_bulk_creation");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    var calendarName = data[i][1];
    CalendarApp.createCalendar(calendarName);
  }
}


The new error I got was:
TypeError:
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getDataRange') createCalendars @ Code.gs:3

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Calendars_bulk_creation i s a variable name.  If you want to use it as a literal value, put it in quotes.  "Calendars_bulk_creation".

Many thanks I will do that. Why would SHEET_NAME not need to be in quotes? I just wish to understand as it helps in the future.
As soon as I added the qoutes though I got the error: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getDataRange')
createCalendars @ Code.gs:3"

I think the assumption from the documentation is that SHEET_NAME is a placeholder you'd replace with an appropriate value.   Your error suggests that getSheetByName returned null, possibly because "Calendars_bulk_creation" was not found?

I take it you're pretty new to  javascript and programming in general?  You should go through a javascript tutorial or two, so that you can understand the components of the code you're trying to produce.

To use Google Apps Scripts effectively, you have to learn the JavaScript basics, like what an expression is, the data types, and how to declare functions and variables. Then read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets. From this page, you will learn, among other things, that the data types string, number, boolean, Date and Array are essential when using Google Apps Script with Google Sheets.
Regarding the code, the method getSheetByName requires a string as a parameter. This string should match the name of a sheet from the related spreadsheet.
As the code is using the getActiveSpreadsheet() method, this code should be used on an Apps Script project contained by a spreadsheet.

Google Apps Script uses JavaScript as a programming language. A tool like Google Gemini might be helpful, but you should be careful, as it could hallucinate due to the large number of ways that JavaScript can be used, so I recommend that before using a tool like Google Gemini to get code to use on Google Apps Script, read https://developers.google.com/apps-scripts/overview the guides and examples thoroughly.
